# Can help me to see what is the real problem?

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am running an asp.net website and try to covert the excel file into CSV file. The code works well when the rows of the excel file is below 100, once I put more than 100 row, Break exception thrown

I am thinking that I am running into deadlock but I don't know how to fix it or confirm the error

Attached with the error message with the picture.

Any helps will do! Appreciate it

```
 try
        {
            //Call Excel Converter to convert the file
            //ExeClass execlass = new ExeClass();
            //string path= Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.xlsx");
            //execlass.CallExcelExeToDataTxt(path);

            // Or specify a specific name in the current dir
            var MyIni1 = new IniFile(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/SettingsforExcel.ini"));

            MyIni1.Write("outfile_name", Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.txt"));
            MyIni1.Write("infile_name", Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.xlsx"));

            //string txtfile_name = MyIni1.Read("outfile_name");
            string infile_name = MyIni1.Read("infile_name");

            //The connection string to the excel file
            // string connstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=excel1.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
            //string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;" + "data source=" + excelpathexcelName.Replace(@"\\", "\\") + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1'"; //此连接只能操作Excel2007之前(.xls)文件
            string connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OleDb.12.0;" + "data source= " + infile_name + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0; HDR=No'"; //此连接可以操作.xls与.xlsx文件 (支持Excel2003 和 Excel2007 的连接字符串)

            //备注： "HDR=yes;"是说Excel文件的第一行是列名而不是数据，"HDR=No;"正好与前面的相反。
            //      "IMEX=1 "如果列中的数据类型不一致，使用"IMEX=1"可必免数据类型冲突。

            //The connection to that file
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstr);
            //The query
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [data$]";
            //The command 
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(/*The query*/strSQL, /*The connection*/conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                OleDbDataReader dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.txt"));
                if (dr1.Read())
                {
                    dt.Load(dr1);
                }

                int iColCount = dt.Columns.Count;

                for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(dt.Columns[i]);
                    if (i < iColCount - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write("\t");
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                // Now write all the rows.

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                        {
                            if (i < iColCount - 1)
                            {
                                sw.Write(dr[i].ToString() + ";");  //add in delimiter in txt file
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sw.Write(dr[i].ToString()); // except for the last row
                            }

                        }
                        //if (i < iColCount - 1)
                        //{
                        //    sw.Write("\t");
                        //}
                    }
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                }
                sw.Close();
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.txt"));
                File.WriteAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.txt"), lines.Skip(1).ToArray());


            }
            catch (OleDbException caught)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Message.ToString();
        }
```

[foo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04HN5.png)

[foo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE6rB.png)

below is the code i using to convert the excel file

Comment: How can anyone guess what your code does? You didn't even post the exception. Besides, why would tasks and deadlocks have anything to do with a *very* small CSV or Excel file?

Comment: Hi I added in the exception

Comment: Whatever your code does, it's probably wrong. It's easy to create a *real* Excel file using a library lke EPPlus. You can load data into a sheet with a single call to `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(myList)`. Reading a CSV file and putting the results into a List<> isn't hard either, but for more complex scenarios you can use a class like CsvHelper. EPPlus makes it very easy to read Excel contents as well

Comment: Use text to show error message would be better

Comment: `catch (OleDbException caught){}` is actually *hiding* any OLEDB related exceptions. Perhaps the OLEDB driver is missing, or targets x86 instead of x64. That's why people use EPPlus instead of the OLEDB driver - you don't need to install anything on the server

Comment: I had checked the convertion from excel file to csv file is successful, and my application startup page is successfully loaded. Just that after it successfully loaded, the application break.

Comment: Is it possible the RAM is not enough? I checked everytime break is around 110~120 Mb

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ADO db provider. I don't remember the exact number of row, but Excel driver will read the top *n* rows and then infer the data type. It's very common Excel have the first rows of a data as numbers but in the following rows, it can be a text. This situation will lead to an exception.

I recommend you to use a specialised library to read Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). In its wiki page you have plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

I had done the debugging line by line and finally figuring out the error is with my innner html tag does not have a close tag when I open it.

I hope this will help someone who facing the problem.